# How do I place the cursor on the first file in vim netrw?

Tags: vim, netrw

When I open a directory in vim it places the cursor at line 1, which is a banner, and then normally I have to go down a few lines before selecting a file. Is there any way to have netrw windows start out with the cursor at the first file?

Answer (score 1):

See `:help g:netrw_banner`.

Letting `let g:netrw_banner = 0` will hide it, press `I` in netrw to bring it back if you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the banner and also position the cursor at first file?

Comment: Actually, now that I've checked it, my vim places the cursor beneath the banner by default (tested on an minimal profile which simply sets `nocompatible` and `filetype plugin on`). Did you mean the first file as opposed to a directory or simply beneath the banner? Which version of vim are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 7.4.52 on OSX netrw version 150. And I tried replacing my .vimrc with only those two commands and still cursor position is at top of banner not the first file.